# Query for Opens from for an email in a Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder, tracking-extract

Is it possible to query for open data from an email in a Journey. I've been having trouble extracting that into a data extension. I'm using this query

```
SELECT c.JobID,c.SubscriberKey
FROM _Open c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT JobID,EmailName 
    FROM _Job 
) j ON j.JobID = c.JobID
WHERE j.EmailName = 'Journey Email 1'
```

My results data extension has EmailName, JobID, and SubscriberKey. There are no errors that result from this however I'm not getting any data either.

Comment: Try deleting the data extension and creating it again. Remember to map the query to the. New data extension

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to execute the query from a child Business Unit. If so, append an `Ent.` prefix to your Data Views:

```sql
SELECT c.JobID, c.SubscriberKey
FROM Ent._Open c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT JobID, EmailName 
    FROM Ent._Job 
) j ON j.JobID = c.JobID
WHERE j.EmailName = 'Journey Email 1'
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm still getting no results.  No errors either. I've also recreated the data extension as "Data_Kid" suggested. Is there a way to query for a Journey by JobID? I guess that would be another question.